# How to properly update a model entity instance in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have some code like belows. This works but I think it's not clear enough and requires me to write lengthy code (assigning each property manually).

```
// POST: /TableA/Edit
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(TableA formdata)
{
    TableA temp = myDB.TableA.First(a=>a.Id == formdata.Id);

    //A foreign key model in another TableB
    var tbb = myDB.TableB.First(a => a.Id == formdata.TableB.Id);
    temp.TableB = tbb;

    //fields in this table
    temp.field1= formdata.field1;
    temp.field2= formdata.field2;
    temp.field3= formdata.field3;

    myDB.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Can I have some code similar to object initializers:

```
    TableA temp = myDB.TableA.First(a=>a.Id == formdata.Id)
    {
        TableB =  myDB.TableB.First(a => a.Id == formdata.TableB.Id),
        field1= formdata.field1,
        field2= formdata.field2,
        field3= formdata.field3,
    }

    myDB.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: I think the first solution is ugly. Can I have some more meaningful way of updating a model.

Comment: the 2nd solution doesn't make any sense. You can't use an object initializer when you're not calling the constructor. The 1st solution isn't THAT ugly...

Comment: But what if I have 100 fields. Write `temp.field1= formdata.field1;` for 100 times?

Comment: BTW: This doesn't really have to do anything with Asp.net MVC 2... It's pure EF and C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using i.e. [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) you could write it like this (possibly have to set up to limit the mapping between the objects to the properties you want copied):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(TableA formdata)
{
    TableA temp = myDB.TableA.First(a=>a.Id == formdata.Id);
    temp.TableB = myDB.TableB.First(a => a.Id == formdata.TableB.Id);

    AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(formdata, temp);
    myDB.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Yes... Object mapping could be something he could use to remove repeatable code. Another thing are extension methods (or public methods for that matter), because Entity classes are partial classes so he can add whatever functionality he needs.

Comment: Not expecting that, but really Magic!

Comment: @Robert Koritnik partial class sounds like what I'm looking for. I will try it if the project schedule permits.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `TryUpdateModel` method

> Updates the specified model instance using values from the controller's current value provider and included properties.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(TableA formdata)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TableA temp = myDB.TableA.First(a=>a.Id == formdata.Id);
        if (TryUpdateModel<TableA>(temp))
        {
            myDB.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

You would be better off calling [Controller.TryUpdateModel Method (TModel, String[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470377.aspx) to prevent properties you don't want to be editable from being added to the form before it's posted. This includes ID's or other fields you don't want the form to post.

Comment: +1 built in mapping with UpdateModel is preferable to external solution if it is sufficient.

Comment: UpdateModel gets me a lot of trouble. That's why I repeatedly write `temp.field1= formdata.field1;`. I'm new to EF, so it's really hard to debug. But thank all the same.